# What Happens to Renderers of Gameobjects that have been Destroyed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, runtime-error, nullreferenceexception

I'm trying to get a reference to all the renderers in the children of my parent gamobject, Some of the gameobjects were destroyed at random. However when I try doing

```
Renderer[] rs = parent.GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>();
```

I end up with missing renderers.

Ok, I thought I will filter out the missing renderers by using a list as shown below.

```
Renderer[] rs;
List<Renderer> r = new List<Renderer>();
        GetComponentsInChildren(r);
        for(int i=0;i<r.Count;i++)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(r[i],null))
            {
                r.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }
        rs = r.ToArray();
```

So I've even tried doing this in the Start Method before using the renderers, but it still causes a null reference exception because the renderers are missing and i can clearly see the missing renderers in my inspector.

I've checked my code and traced it and I'm 100% certain that I'm getting the references for the renderers **after** destroying the children objects in a *different* script.

I even tried the code below as suggested by StarManta @ https://forum.unity.com/threads/differentiate-between-null-and-missing-references-in-script.376491/

```
bool IsMissingReference(Object unknown)
    {
        try
        {
            unknown.GetInstanceID();
            return false;
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling Destroy on an object puts in in a queue for later destruction. Perhaps try DestroyImmediate() to guarantee it happens before your other script starts.